# Set Accept header on ServiceStack JsonServiceClient

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack, github-api

I am using the ServiceStack.JsonServiceClient to attempt to make a URL request with a custom value for the Accept header, but am unable to find a way to make the call.

The service call is to retrieve the topics for a repository through the GitHub API. This is currently a preview feature, and requires additional information to be sent on the accept header as a custom media type. (https://developer.github.com/v3/repos)

I'm using Service Stack and making a C# .NET call to the API endpoint, and I'm struggling to find the appropriate way to update the accept header on the request. I've tried two strageies.

1. Create an HttpWebRequest with the header and pass it to the client

   ```
           Uri uri = new Uri(requestUrl, UriKind.Absolute);
           HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(uri);
           webRequest.Accept = "application/vnd.github.mercy-preview+json";

           HttpWebResponse webResponse = client.Get<HttpWebResponse>(webRequest);
   ```

   The `requestUrl` is a string of the form `https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}?access_token={token}`. It successfully creates both the Uri and the HttpWebRequest objects but then throws an exception on the `client.Get`, claiming `Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.`

   Calling the API with the string URL: `HttpWebResponse webResponse = client.Get<HttpWebResponse>(requestUrl);` succeeds without issue (but the custom header value is not passed).
2. Set the header on the client itself. `client.AddHeaders` throws an exception because `Accept` is a restricted header. I have been unable to find any other way to set the header directly on the client (although this would probably be the nicest solution).

Thank you, and let me know if there is anything else that I can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `RequestFilter` to modify the `HttpWebRequest` before requests are sent, e.g:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(baseUrl) {
    RequestFilter = req => req.Accept = acceptHeader
};
```

Note: ServiceStack's [C#/.NET Service Clients](http://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-client) should only be used for calling ServiceStack Services. For calling 3rd Party APIs you should instead use [HTTP Utils](http://docs.servicestack.net/http-utils), e.g:

```
var body = url.GetStringFromUrl(requestFilter: req => {
    req.Accept = acceptHeader;
});
```